# Why setupProxy.js does not log in react app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, react-scripts

I have ejected react scripts, and I have the following in my setupProxy.js.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
   proxy({
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
    onProxyReq: function onProxyReq(proxyReq, req, res) {
    console.log(
      chalk.red(
        'Request'
      )
    );
  },
  onError(err, req, res) {
   console.log(err);
  },
  secure: false,
  target: "http://www.google.com"
})
```

I would expect the above to proxy, and log every request going out from the react app, but this is not the case. Is there a config that I need to add in Webpack ?
Thank you

Comment: can you share the entire file? you're missing an end brace, just want to make sure you don't have a syntax error. also are you looking for the logs in the browser console or the terminal?

Comment: I 'm sure this is not a syntax error, in any case there  I'm looking for logs at the terminal. I suspect that this has to do with something wrong with the Webpack config.

Comment: does it work on an app where you have not ejected?

Comment: I'm trying that now :)

Comment: On a newly created app, it works both with ejected scripts, and without ejected scripts. That's why I believe that this has to do with webpack config somehow

Comment: did you make modifications to the dev server file?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue.